# I have a function in my .profile file that I pipe commands to. How can I do this?

Tags: pipe, bash

Sorry if the question title is confusing. I'm not really sure how to word this question.

I have a function in my .profile file that is a shortcut for sublime text:

```
function s() { subl "$@" & }
export -f s
```

But, when I do `ls | s` I don't get the output of ls in my Sublime window. When I do `ls | subl` I do get the output in the Sublime window. Can I modify my function to work correctly for `s` and `s file.txt` and `ls | s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read any input you need before backgrounding.

```
s() { 
    # Is stdin a terminal?
    if [[ -t 0 ]]
    then
        #not piping
        subl "$@" &
    else
        #piping
        contents=$(cat)
        subl "$@" <<< "$contents" &
    fi
}
```

Comment: You don't have to slurp up the contents first: `cat - | subl`